# Excel - Charts with varying number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have an existing spreadsheet and macro process I'm trying to improve, and I have multiple tables which refresh for each client, and can have between 3 and 6 rows of data (depending on whether someone has enough history to fill all 6 rows). There is a chart attached to the table which works fine when all 6 are there, but when there are fewer rows, the chart leaves a blank space on the X-axis to account for that table row.

Example of the table when full

```
Quarter Value
2021Q1  10
2021Q2  7
2021Q3  4
2021Q4  2
2022Q1  1
2022Q2  0
```

Example of the table when less than full

```
Quarter Value
2021Q3  4
2021Q4  2
2022Q1  1
2022Q2  0
```

On the second table, there will be places on the X-axis for values, rather than knowing there's no data and only showing 4 places

Is it possible for excel charts to refresh dynamically depending on what is in the source? I have found plenty of guides for what to do with the chart lines when there is no value, but not to ignore a whole row from the report.

Comment: You can do this programmatically, where you edit the dataseries.  Please display the code you're using, as you mentioned a macro process.

Comment: I would refer to @JonPeltier excellent website on [dynamic charts](https://peltiertech.com/dynamic-charts/) and see which technique matches your needs. Based on your description, you may not need VBA at all, just use a dynamic named range. But Jon also has information on VBA supported dynamic charts as well.